Flask update server in firefox doesnt work
I am using Flask in VS Code and i have some codes in use for my website which i am trying to create but i have one problem: when I make a print statement or also a route, at the first time it works perfect, but if i want to change it (change the print statement or the route) it doesn't update it on the website server but if i call it with the old name which doesn't exist anymore it works. for example: @xy.route('/SignUp') change to @xy.route('/signup'). if i call it with the new /signup it doesnt work but if i call it with the old /SignUp which doesnt exist anymore in my coding it works.
app.run(debug=True) is on and also app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0,
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
Thanks for your help
here are the different files. all files are in the website directory except main.py is outside the directory
main.py:

from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':  #only if we run this file we are going to execute the following line
    app.run(debug=True)     # debux true means it is going to aktualisieren when we change something

init.py:
print("Importing website module...")
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views,url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth,url_prefix='/')

    return app

views.py: interesting is that on my website it comes "Welcome to the Homepage!" which was the old print statement which is not anymore there. "Welcome!" doesn't get displayed
print("Loading views module...")

from flask import Blueprint

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return "Welcome!"


auth.py:
print("Loading auth module...")

from flask import Blueprint

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return "<p>login</p>"

@auth.route('/logout')
def log_out():
    return "<p>logout</p>"

@auth.route('/signup')
def sign_up():
    return "<p>SignUp</p>"


During the control process for my post/question I found the solution. I have to run the page at its own so the update occurs. Before that I only had run the main.py so the server went on

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
